# Different behavior in WindowsLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jpopupmenu

I want to show a popupmenu, while using Metal L&F it will do these behavior.

- single click: it printed "pressed" and show menu
- double pressed: it printed "pressed" and show menu too.

Yes it is I needed. But when using WindowsLookAndFeel, it not same as those.
when twice pressed it just hide menu and not printed "pressed". why it have difference behavior between two L&F?

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 
 public class Popup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        menu.add("item");
        f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("pressed");
            }
        });
        f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                menu.show(f, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Typically you would use [JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu))

Comment: *show menu too."*  By 'too' DYM a 2nd (different) menu?

Comment: You will need to monitor pressed, released and clicked events and check [MouseEvent#isPopupTrigger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#isPopupTrigger()) as each platform will have different triggers, that's how different platforms work

Comment: For [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean consumeEvent = UIManager.getBoolean("PopupMenu.consumeEventOnClose");
// Consume the event so that normal processing stops.
if(consumeEvent && !(src instanceof MenuElement)) {
    me.consume();
}
```

I have found the problems, because of this property is different
so end it